# Working with Date and Calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a datepicker where the user selects a date and then a checkbox on what type of period he wants to get the date from. For example:

User selects the 1. of November and selects the checkbox "Month" in this case the end date will be increased by 1 and even if this sound simple enough its slowly starting to annoy me alot!

The problem is that Java doesnt have a great date object that works for this kind of thing so i thought that i would use Calendar but it isnt easy to increment a calendar date take for instance the following example:

```
endDate.set(startDate.YEAR, startDate.MONTH+1, startDate.DATE);
```

in theory this would increment the month by one being one larger than the start date. This works in about 90 % of the months EXECPT from December if you increase the month by 1 in December then the integer month return 13 same thing happens for `startDate.DATE;` and `startDate.Year;`

My question is isnt there an easier way to do this? i could make a ton of If sentences but i really think that it is kinda redundant.

Comment: @svz The month starts with 0 (for January).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `add` method of `java.util.Calendar`.

```
endDate.set(startDate.YEAR, startDate.MONTH, startDate.DATE);
if(some_condition) {
   endDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
}
```

Comment: in this case wouldnt it be endDate.add(endDate.MONTH,1);

Comment: `Calendar.MONTH` is just static variable indicating the month. And this line "startDate.YEAR, startDate.MONTH, startDate.DATE" I just copied from you question. The point is you need to use `add` method of `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard recomendation here is to look at [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) (see [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jodatime/index.html) for more info). It's a much more consistent/capable API with none of the threading issues that plague the standard Java date/formatting APIs and as such is widely used and accepted.

In terms of what you want above, I would suggest something like:

```
LocalDate d = ...
LocalDate nd = d.plusMonths(1);
```

The above will correctly handle month/year rollovers.

Comment: do i have to download a plugin if i use eclipse?

Comment: No. Just download the jar, or reference it in your pom.xml if you're using Maven

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Calendar.add()` to add values to the calendar value, e.g. `Calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)` this adds one month and takes into account that January is after December.

Comment: Will this increment the month aswell if the date is forexample 31. of January?

Comment: Yes. It will take you to 28. or 29. of February.

Comment: Then what do you want if you add one month to the 31. of January? 2nd or 3rd of March? Then you have to add 31 days.

Comment: I misread your statement i thought it was DATE, 1 :) i am sorry!